# How do i run a cron schedule a DAG in airflow so that it runs at 10:30 cst on first of one month and 10 cst on the other days of the month ? I have tr

Tags: cron, airflow, scheduling

Like i have tried multiple combinations in cron guru but havent found any possible solution.

I have these two expressions to combine

30 10 1 * *

10 12 2-31 * *

Answer (score -1):

You cannot implement this in one cron expression, you have two options to do that:

1. easy one: create two copy of the dag, each one with its own cron expression
2. hard one: create a [Timetable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html) and register it in an Airflow plugin, then you can use pass it to your dag as `timetable` argument instead of `schedule_interval`.
   In this timetable, you can implement two methods:

   - `next_dagrun_info`: The scheduler uses this to learn the timetable’s regular schedule
   - `infer_manual_data_interval`: When a DAG run is manually triggered (from the web UI, for example), the scheduler uses this method to learn about how to reverse-infer the out-of-schedule run’s data interval (not mandatory).